# How to avoid many import iterations while generating sub assets?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a `ScriptedImporter` that generates other assets in the same directory.

Whenever it happens, import progress bar pops in again, this time like `Importing (iteration N)`.

I've tried to use [AssetDatabase.DisallowAutoRefresh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.DisallowAutoRefresh.html) to circumvent this behavior but that failed.

**Question:**

How to prevent subsequent import iterations and rather group them to happen all at once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By directly putting things in `AssetImportContext` this problem will go.

**Advantages:**

- asset is a script and not a blank icon anymore
- it's importing faster
- assets are **read-only**, very interesting :D
- everything is in one place
- less assets to deal with

**Disadvantages:**

- all sub assets are in asset, pretty hard to navigate in project browser
- assets needs unique names, quite easy actually
- things like textures lose fully featured importer

A cool trick is to make a ZIP file in which you put whatever you want but then give it another extension so you can differentiate file formats.

I came up with this to decorate `ScriptableObject`s trees:

```
[PublicAPI]
public interface IAsset
{
    [NotNull]
    string Name { get; set; } // this can be customized but should be unique then

    [NotNull]
    [ItemNotNull]
    IEnumerable<IAsset> GetDescendants(); // to traverse tree

    [NotNull]
    string GetPrefix(); // for generating name automatically
}

public static class IAssetExtensions
{
    public static void AddSelfAndDescendants(
        [NotNull] this AssetImportContext context, [NotNull] IAsset asset, IAssetFlags flags = IAssetFlags.Default)
    {
        if (context is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (asset is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(asset));

        var generator = new UniqueNameGenerator();

        var queue = new Queue<IAsset>(new[] {asset});

        while (queue.Any())
        {
            var dequeue = queue.Dequeue();

            if (dequeue is IAsset iAsset)
            {
                var descendants = iAsset.GetDescendants();

                foreach (var descendant in descendants)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(descendant);
                }
            }

            if (flags.HasFlagFast(IAssetFlags.Rename) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dequeue.Name))
                dequeue.Name = generator.GetName(dequeue.GetPrefix());

            context.AddObjectToAsset(dequeue.Name, dequeue as Object);
        }

        context.SetMainObject(asset as Object);
    }
}

public sealed class UniqueNameGenerator
{
    public UniqueNameGenerator([CanBeNull] IDictionary<string, int> dictionary = null)
    {
        Dictionary = dictionary ?? new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }

    [NotNull]
    private IDictionary<string, int> Dictionary { get; }

    [NotNull]
    public string GetName([NotNull] string prefix)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prefix))
            throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or whitespace.", nameof(prefix));

        if (!Dictionary.ContainsKey(prefix))
            Dictionary.Add(prefix, default);

        var suffix = Dictionary[prefix];
        var unique = $"{prefix} {suffix}";

        Dictionary[prefix]++;

        return unique;
    }
}
```

Summarized but you get the general idea.